# concatenar 2 variables y mandarlo a Endpoint

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de enviar 2 respuestas diferentes a un solo enpoint me podrian apoyar con alguna explicación por favor, aqui adjunto mi codigo :

```js
function myIccid(val) {
            var baitcard = document.getElementById("baitcard").value
  
            fetch(
                    `${getUrl}/api/iccid/${val}/direct_number/${baitcard}/exists`,
                    requestOptions)
                .then(response => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(result => {
                    console.log(result.exists);
                    if (result.exists === true) {
                        alert("Verificando clave ICCID : " + result.exists)

                    } else if (result.exists === false) {
                        alert("Verificando clave ICCID : " + result.exists)
                        document.getElementById("limpiarIccid").value = "";
                    }
                }).catch(error => console.log('error', error));
        }
```

```html
 <input type="text" id="limpiarIccid" name="iccid" placeholder="Clave ICCID" onchange="myIccid(this.value)"
                required />
      
            <input type="text" name="baitcard" id="baitcard" placeholder="Número telefónico de la tarjeta"
                onchange="myIccid(this.value)" required />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo prefiero guardar cosas como una URL que se esta componiendo en una variable para poder ver su contenido y que no vengan por ahí los errores.
Por ejemplo, puedes sustituir esto:

```
function myIccid(val) {
    var baitcard = document.getElementById("baitcard").value

    fetch(
        `${getUrl}/api/iccid/${val}/direct_number/${baitcard}/exists`,
         requestOptions
    ).then(response => {
    ...
```

x lo siguiente:

```
function myIccid(val) {
    var baitcard = document.getElementById("baitcard").value
    var endpoint = `${getUrl}/api/iccid/${val}/direct_number/${baitcard}/exists`;
    console.log(endpoint); return; // HACK:

    fetch(
        endpoint,
        requestOptions
    ).then(response => {
    ...
```

Eliminar la línea con la traza, una vez compruebes que la dirección del *endpoint* es correcta. También puedes copiarla y probarla en alguna app para probar APIs como *postman*.